# ReactJS: Material-Table search detail panel

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using Material-table (https://material-table.com/#/) for my project.  I have implemented the "detail panel" feature (https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/detail-panel) and have enabled search feature as well.

To my knowledge, the "search" function will only search against "string" values in any column in the table.

My detail panel contains text inside of an html pre tag.

```
detailPanel={rowData => {
          return <pre style={preCss}>{rowData.releaseNote}</pre>;
        }}
```

What I want to know is:

Is it possible to also make the "search" function search against data in the "detail panel".  If yes, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having same issue, I believe I found a workaround.  I added the `"rowData.releaseNote"` as a column entry in main table.  But then I zeroed out the headerStyle and cellStyle widths and set `display:none`.  So essentially, the data exists as an invisible column in the table.

```
 {
    title: "",
    field: "releaseNote",
    sorting: false,
    filtering: false,
    headerStyle: { display: "none", width: "0px", maxWidth: "0px" },

    cellStyle: { display: "none", width: "0px", maxWidth: "0px" }
  }
```

Comment: Where do you add this piece of code? Inside the detailPanel property of the MaterialTable?

Comment: @LH No, I think he added it columns array which is passed as a prop to Material Table component

Answer (score 2):

Wai Ha Lee's solution will cause weird spacing in Columns in my Material-table, I use this one to solve the problem:

```
      {
        title: "",
        field: "releaseNote",
        sorting: false,
        filtering: false,
        hidden: true,
        searchable: true,
        width: "0px"
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding:

```
{ 
   hidden: true,
}
```

should work.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, it is not an obvious one. The other answer has a lot more code, and does not highlight that the important/essential part of the solution is just the `hidden` rule. This answer implies that "hidden" is the only piece needed to solve the issue. That said, it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are discouraged.